# WP_Query inside setup_postdata()

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to use `setup_postdata()` to display the contents of another page (lets call this page "X") on my page (lets call this page "Y").

However, X's page has two `WP_Queries` which work perfect when viewing that page alone. But when visiting Y's page, the content after the wp query gets messed up.

I know this is because my `wp_reset_postdata()` is resetting the `setup_postdata()` loop.

Is there anyway to reset the QUERY without reflecting the outer `setup_postdata()` loop?

**X's page**

```
<?php
get_header();
$the_slug = 'work-with-us';
$args = array('name'        => $the_slug,
              'post_type'   => 'page',
              'post_status' => 'publish',
              'numberposts' => 1);
$my_posts = get_posts($args);
global $post;
$post = $my_posts[0];
setup_postdata( $post );
include 'inc-work-with-us.php';
wp_reset_postdata();
get_footer();
?>
```

**Y's page query**

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'positions',
    'orderby' => 'title',
  );
  $location_loop = new WP_Query($args);
  if($location_loop->have_posts()) :

    while($location_loop->have_posts()) : $location_loop->the_post();
    echo 'hey';
    endwhile;

  endif;
  wp_reset_query();
?>
```